# Cross platform group video?

Tags: video, skype, conferencing

I'm looking for a free Skype alternative that supports group video calls and is cross platform (Windows, OSX, Linux).
Any ideas?

Comment: Even skype does not support group video for linux,  http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=809765&view=findpost&p=3365403

Answer (score 1):

There is a service called oovoo http://www.oovoo.com thats supposed to support up to 12 people and is free

if you have the resources you could also try setting up a webbased application on a server such as Big Blue Button. its flash based and you host all your webconference youreself so security isnt an issue

Answer (score 1):

These days Google Plus Hangouts work really great, I ended up using that :)

Edit: explanation

It's a service integrated with Google+ called Hangouts. It allows you to set up meetings with several people with the option of sharing webcams. Whereas most of these services cost money (such as Skype premium), Google+ Hangouts is completely free :)

Comment: Care to explain a little bit more about Google+ Hangouts? People new to it might not believe your word for it without some explanation